# Is a standard power outlet sufficient for a 2.8 kW oven?

Tags: electrical, oven

I'm moving some of my kitchen appliances around, where the oven is going where the Dish Washer was. The Consumer Unit has just a single breaker for all kitchen appliances (except the cooker hob, which has a separate breaker). Both, the Oven, and the Dishwasher are currently wired directly in to the wall outlet (i.e. not via a 13 Amp plug/socket).

So, after moving can I connect the Oven to the existing wall outlet that currently used for the Dishwasher. By numbers I'm guessing it should be fine, as even a 13Amp socket should supply enough power, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: This is presumably from the UK, as they are the only ones I know of that have 13 amp sockets.

Comment: From the sounds of things, you are in the UK. I don't know the electric codes there, but it's common when sizing circuits to apply a 125% demand factor to leave some overhead in capacity. If this is so where you are, applying this factor kicks you over the 13A. You would need at least a 15A circuit.

Comment: Yup, I'm in the UK. I guess I'll just run the existing wiring through to the new location.